Name for a property of a binary relation
Is there a common name for the following property of a binary relation $R$:
$$x\mathrel{R}y\quad\text{and}\quad x\mathrel{R}z\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y\mathrel{R}z\quad\text{or}\quad z\mathrel{R}y\quad\text{or}\quad y=z\,?$$
Or a common name for a relation $R$ that satisfies the property above and additionally is acyclic (i.e., there are no $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ with $x_1\mathrel{R}\cdots\mathrel{R}x_k\mathrel{R}x_1$)?
A linear order that contains such an acyclic relation $R$ is called a perfect elimination order. But I cannot use this name for $R$ itself, because $R$ is not an order.
